# Errors in process running in screen session while not logged in

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen, sage-math

I'm trying to run a Sage notebook server in a screen session (though I don't think the specific program is relevant because I've seen similar behavior for other programs).  While I'm logged in to the machine (via ssh), it behaves as expected, regardless of whether its screen session is attached.  After I've logged out (leaving the program running in the detached screen session), the server continues to run, but begins to have errors that seem related to not being able to see/access certain files.  If I ssh back in (without touching the detached screen session), the errors go away.

This is a pretty vanilla Ubuntu Server 14.04 (32-bit) install.  What's different between being logged in and being logged out that could cause this?

---

(This relates to my [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40732874/1495011).)

Comment: Can you copy-paste the errors in your question please?

Comment: I will add the error (and the related SO question), but I left it out because the error isn't very helpful and it takes a bit of digging before it starts to look like a file access problem.  Also, I have seen similar behavior in another program, so I don't think it's anything specific to Sage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, *something* is not set up that automatically is when a session is open.

An example would be a program accessing /run/ when you don't have any session (however, in this case the screen instance would count as a login).

Given that you have eCryptfs on your home dir, that's most likely the culprit. Even though the notepad is elsewhere, it may be trying to access your $HOME for eg. reading configuration files.

Given that you are already running the notebooks in `/var/sage/` I would run `export HOME=/var/sage/` so it thinks it is the full home dir. That should hopefully solve the issues.

Comment: That was it!  I will probably create a separate user to run the server.